# Uploading pictures on a website/server

Tags: word-usage

When you upload pictures on a website/server, can you say that the pictures are "up there"? That is, "on the website/server"?

> When can I see our road trip pictures?
>
> Sorry, I forgot to tell you that the pictures are already **up there**.

(In that sentence, "up there" is a way to say "on the website" or "on the server".)

Can you use the word "up" to refer to something on a website/server? Or do you have to say something like "on there" or "up on there" to make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming enough context has been set, so that the hearer knows what website you are referring to, there are plenty of ways you could say this:

> Sorry, I forgot to tell you that the pictures **are already up there**.

I have no problem with that wording, although there are several similar ways the same information could be conveyed:

> Sorry, I forgot to tell you that the pictures **are already up**.
>    Sorry, I forgot to tell you that the pictures **are up there already**.
>    Sorry, I forgot to tell you that the pictures **have already been uploaded**.
>    Sorry, I forgot to tell you that the pictures **are up already.**
>    Sorry, I forgot to tell you that the pictures **are on the server already.**
>    Sorry, I forgot to say that I **put** the pictures **up on there already.**
>    Sorry, I forgot to mention that **I uploaded the pictures already**.

I think I'd understand all of these just fine, and any of them would work for day-to-day conversation.

In a more formal context, I'd be inclined to use *uploaded* instead of *up*, and I'd probably leave off the "there," which isn't necessary:

> Sorry, I forgot to tell you that I've **already uploaded the pictures**.

Comment: +1 in my shop we post pictures and videos and scripts for clients to download all the time, and I would most likely notify a client by emailing "Hey, Bob -- just wanted to let you know the video's up. Here's the link."

Comment: I find it interesting that what seems me the simplest and most likely form doesn't figure at all in your list - *...the pictures are already **there***.

Comment: @Fumble - That one works quite nicely, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Correct.  "Up" as referring to content on a webserver, is an informal usage referring to the process of "uploading" from a local computer to a server, a network, the Internet, etc.